# Firefox addon SDK replace request

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried to replace by a local script the url of scripts loaded by websites.

I tried to `channel.redirectTo()` with `data.url()` and `chrome://` (with `contentaccessible=yes` flag in manifest), but doesn't work, so I compared a regex pattern, if true, it will cancel the XHR GET request.

For example

```
<script src="http://url/to/script.js"></script>
```

become

```
<script src="resource://url/to/new/script.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="chrome://url/to/new/script.js"></script>
```

Now I need to replace the url or inject my new script to the page

main.js

```
var listener = function (event) {
    var channel = event.subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
    var match = someFunctionToMatchRegex(channel.URI.spec);
    if (match) {
        channel.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
    }
};

events.on("http-on-modify-request", listener);
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to detect url like  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`and replace it with a local version.

Comment: do you have cr and ci imorted correctly?

Comment: `var { Ci, Cr } = require("chrome");`
I don't have any error with it.
I post another topic about how I tried to inject jquery, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328849/firefox-addon-sdk-inject-jquery thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a [redirect module here](https://github.com/jetpack-labs/pathfinder/blob/master/lib/redirect.js) which is a good example for what you want to do.  You might be able to use it, though the module only takes specific urls and not reg expressions at the moment.  I'd certainly take a pull request to make this change though.

The code basically just uses `redirectTo` as you mention, so something else is wrong.