# Firefox addon SDK inject jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The script in `$(document).ready(...)` doesn't work, any ideas why ?
It seems the script I try to inject is loaded in the end.

Here my code:

main.js

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen: 'start',
    contentScriptFile: data.url('inject.js')
});
```

inject.js

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "resource://directoryOfMyAddon/data/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="helloworld"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#helloworld").text("Hello, world!");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks O=)

Answer (score 3):

You can inject jquery using the technique you describe, but depending on the `contentScriptWhen` setting in your `page-mod` options **you won't see the `.ready()`** as the content script will be attached only when after `load` (`contentScriptWhen="end"` (default)) or `DOMContentLoaded` (`contentScriptWhen="ready"`).

You could use `contentScriptWhen="start"`, but at that point there likely isn't a node yet where you could append your `<script>` tag to.

However, I should mention that it is strongly discouraged (read: won't pass AMO review) to inject jquery into random pages, as this might interfere with the jquery version that might have been already loaded by a page (or whatever else the site assigned to `$`).

Instead it would be better if all your code would reside in your content script(s).

Comment: See the comment below ;)

Answer (score 1):

See [the docs for loading content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Loading_Content_Scripts). `contentScriptFile` accepts an array as an argument, so you can attach multiple scripts.

That said, page scripts (like your hello world) and content scripts cannot share variables for security reasons. It can be circumvented, but i can't imagine why there would be jQuery code on an HTML page that doesn't inject jQuery itself.

Comment: I'm trying to detect url like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` and replace it with a local version. It's injected, but the script in the body isn't loaded correctly.
See how I block jquery if already exists on the page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189622/firefox-addon-sdk-replace-request Thanks

Comment: Content scripts and page scripts can't share variables, so injecting your version of JQuery won't make it available to the page, only to your extension's content scripts. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Ok, thanks, so do you have any docs about the possibility to circumvented it ? I want to inject a latest local version of jquery for enhance privacy, speed, bandwidth and reduce bugs.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23351862/1720014). But then you'll need to worry about devs using deprecated functions, devs who might have edited the source of their JQuery file with custom functions (bad practice, but still a possibility), and the improvements to the user seem marginal at best.