# communication between web page script and content script and main.js(Add-on code) script

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**UPDATE:** Sorry, this example works, I found a minor bug and fixed in my full source code.
But I still want somebody who know better then me to give a good answer to this question about how to achieve communication between web page script and content script and main.js(Add-on code) script, also please answer how we can access localStorage from web page script and send to add-on script.

---

I cannot find how to build correctly a basic communication between:

**page script -> content script -> add-on script**

and vice versa

**add-on script -> content script -> page script**

[image]

please notice that I understand **page script** as the original webpage script, it is not in a sandbox. The **page script** is from webpage header:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Add-on script** is main.js and **content scrip**t is attached contentScriptFile from PageMod

This is what i know .

I have tried this and it is not working:

**main.js** add-on script:

```
 pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("content.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    onAttach: function(worker) { 

        worker.port.on("message_from_content_script", function(data) { 
            worker.port.emit("message_to_page_script",mainStorage);
        });


     },
     attachTo: ["existing","top", "frame"]
  });
```

**content script:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { 


        self.port.emit("message_from_content_script", "some text");


});
```

as you see I have tried so far only to make a communication between content script and add-on script, but it is not working.   Please somebody show me an example of how to achieve:

**page script -> content script -> add-on script**

and vice versa

**add-on script -> content script -> page script**

Comment: Please read the docs, this is documented there.

Answer (score 1):

There is extensive documentation, including examples, on [how to communicate between page scripts and content scripts using custom DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts#Using_Custom_DOM_Events).

Alternatively, you can use [unsafeWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Accessing_the_DOM#unsafeWindow), but there are potential [security issues](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow), and your extension will probably get rejected from addons.mozilla.org (AMO)