# Calling webpage's Javascript function through addon script

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm learning firefox addon development using the new AddOn SDK. I'm creating a simple utility addon which autohides the comments on [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com) Problems Page.
Now, to hide comments section, there's a option on problem page which calls a javascript function to do so. Currently I temporarily achieved the functionality by simulating a click on this option, but it uses *unsafewindow* which is not recommended.

Here's the **main.js**

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
    var worker = tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile : data.url("autoHide.js")
    });

    worker.port.emit('hideComments', tabs.activeTab.url);
});
```

And **autoHide.js**

```
self.port.on('hideComments', function(url) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('comments_sh');
    //toggleComments();
    elem = elem.parentNode;
    simulateClick(elem);

});

function simulateClick(a) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, unsafeWindow,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  a.dispatchEvent(evt);      
}
```

The function which I want to call is `toggleComments()`.

**So my question is** How can I call a javascript function of WebPage through Addon Script or ContentScript ??

Comment: You can inject a script to the page adding the event listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a simple non-navigation click would work for you, [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) should be sufficient:

```
self.port.on('hideComments', function(url) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('comments_sh');
    elem.parentNode.click();
});
```

[General reference about interacting with page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts).

Comment: Ok, this worked. However I'm more interested in knowing how to communicate to page script and elements through addon script. Any reference or resource will be helpful.

Comment: Added a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts

Comment: @willma Since this came up more than once, I now created a wiki-answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378116/how-can-my-add-on-sdk-content-script-interact-with-website-page-script/24378117#24378117

Answer (score 1):

Your generic question at the end [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349755/communication-between-web-page-script-and-content-script-and-main-jsadd-on-code) [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916203/executing-documents-functions), but I think there's an easier solution in this circumstance.

What happens if you replace `simulateClick` with

```
function simulateClick(a) {
  a.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click'));      
}
```

?

If that doesn't work, then you'll have to edit to page's js code to add a custom event listener that will run the same function that is run on click then dispatch that custom event from the add-on's content script, as described in the answer to the first question I linked to.